# Function to search columns and tally data

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, vlookup

I am wondering if I can write a function to search a column in my spreadsheet for a specific name, then return x number of values within the row(s) that contain the name. For example...

[image]

M4 holds the function. The function searches Columns D, G, and J to find a match of the name in L4 (Owen). Owen's name can occur multiple times in following rows. The function returns a cell value, say B4, in M4.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I implement a search to continue searching down the column for another instance of the search_key and summate the results

- **paste in M4 cell:**

  ```
  =COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY({D:D;G:G;J:J}, "where Col1 contains '"&L4&"'", 0)))*B4
  ```

Comment: @ElliotPressman https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -1):

> function searches columns D, G, and J to find a match of the name in L4. the function returns a cell value, say B4, in M4

- **paste in M4 cell:**

  ```
  =IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(L4, {D:D;G:G;J:J}, 1, 0))<>"", B4, )
  ```

Comment: If the lookup column (the first column of range) contains 2 or more values exactly equal to search_key, the 1st value found is returned. How do I implement a search to continue searching down the column for another instance of the search_key and summate the results?